# php fopen with special charector

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, special-characters, fopen

I am using Laravel and i want to give a download button for AWS file

URL: `https://gzfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/1447528989_ñóñóñóñóñóñóñó ñó ñó.zip`

The issue is that i want to rename the file before downloading so that i can rename the file to its original name. I have the original name saved in DB.

When i try to fopen this URL, its give me an error, The issue is with only files with special charaters like (ñó).

Please guide me how to fopen a URL with special char set OR how to rename a file before download from AWS.

Comment: url-encode it, so that the utf chars don't get mangled at some point? you can't rename a download before downloading it, since you're just fetching a url. the filename you eventually write that data out to is what counts, and that's completely under your control.

Comment: [php urlencode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: @MarcB Do i url-encode it before the fopen? Well if you are referring to that, then there is also an issue with it too. When i url-encode it and try to fopen it, Its says the files not found, because the file i saved without encoding and we are trying to access it with encoded URL.

Comment: urlencode the filename component. url-encoding the entire url won't work, since you'd be doing `http://etc...` -> `http%3A%2F%2Fetc...`, which is no longer a url.

Comment: The thing is my files name on AWS is **1447961765_ñóñó abc.zip** so when i will url-encode this name it will become **1447961765_%C3%B1%C3%B3%C3%B1%C3%B3%20abc.zip**.
as you can see the file name is messed up so now if i FOPEN this file, it will give me an error of file not found

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php - http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php#117312